# Upgrade to Spring 3.2 on Websphere 8.5 error: Resource annotations on DispatcherServlet will be ignored

Tags: java, spring, websphere, websphere-8

I've tried to upgrade **Spring** version from **3.1.2** to **3.2.8** on the **WebSphere 8.5**, but I've got the error:

> CWNEN0047W: Resource annotations on the fields of the
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet class will be
>   ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the
>   exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext

The jar `spring-web-3.2.8.RELEASE.jar` is present in the WAR/WEB-INF/lib directory. The archive is not damaged, the `WebApplicationContext` class is present there. Everything looks like before, only the spring version is higher.

**Everything is working with Spring 3.1.2** with the same maven build configuration and EAR descriptors! But after changing Spring version (and nothing more), the mentioned error occurs.

Is there anything special that must be done when upgrading Spring version on Websphere? Or it's just a kind of incompatibility?

That call comes somewhere from `JmxMBeanServer`. It comes in the web application initialization phase, when the EAR is deployed/updated from IBM RAD. Full stack trace included:

> [5/8/14 10:12:42:866 CEST] 0000004b InjectionProc W   CWNEN0047W:
>   Resource annotations on the fields of the
>   org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet class will be
>   ignored. The annotations could not be obtained because of the
>   exception : java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
>   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verifyImpl(Native Method)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:93)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.verify(J9VMInternals.java:91)     at
>   java.lang.J9VMInternals.prepare(J9VMInternals.java:490)   at
>   java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:605)     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.getAllDeclaredFields(InjectionProcessor.java:554)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessor.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessor.java:722)
>     at
>   com.ibm.wsspi.injectionengine.InjectionProcessorContextImpl.processAllAnnotations(InjectionProcessorContextImpl.java:50)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processAnnotations(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:750)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.AbstractInjectionEngine.processInjectionMetaData(AbstractInjectionEngine.java:559)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.SharedInjectionEngineImpl.processInjectionMetaData(SharedInjectionEngineImpl.java:208)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.injectionengine.ReferenceContextImpl.process(ReferenceContextImpl.java:838)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.populateJavaNameSpace(WebAppImpl.java:1112)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebAppImpl.initialize(WebAppImpl.java:328)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebGroupImpl.addWebApplication(WebGroupImpl.java:88)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.VirtualHostImpl.addWebApplication(VirtualHostImpl.java:169)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApp(WSWebContainer.java:749)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.WSWebContainer.addWebApplication(WSWebContainer.java:634)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:426)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:718)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1173)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1370)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:639)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:968)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:772)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplicationDynamically(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1367)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2172)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:445)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitImpl.start(CompositionUnitImpl.java:123)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.start(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:388)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.access$500(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:116)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl$1.run(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:663)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAs(ContextManagerImpl.java:5459)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.auth.ContextManagerImpl.runAsSystem(ContextManagerImpl.java:5585)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.core.SecurityContext.runAsSystem(SecurityContext.java:255)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:677)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.CompositionUnitMgrImpl.startCompositionUnit(CompositionUnitMgrImpl.java:621)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1259)
>     at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.Trampoline.invoke(MethodUtil.java:49)    at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:60)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:37)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:611)     at
>   sun.reflect.misc.MethodUtil.invoke(MethodUtil.java:256)   at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean$4.run(RequiredModelMBean.java:1148)
>     at
>   java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:252)
>     at
>   com.ibm.oti.security.CheckedAccessControlContext.securityCheck(CheckedAccessControlContext.java:30)
>     at
>   sun.misc.JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.doIntersectionPrivilege(JavaSecurityAccessWrapper.java:41)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invokeMethod(RequiredModelMBean.java:1142)
>     at
>   javax.management.modelmbean.RequiredModelMBean.invoke(RequiredModelMBean.java:995)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:848)
>     at
>   com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:774)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl$1.run(AdminServiceImpl.java:1335)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.security.util.AccessController.doPrivileged(AccessController.java:118)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.AdminServiceImpl.invoke(AdminServiceImpl.java:1228)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.AdminServiceDelegator.invoke(AdminServiceDelegator.java:181)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.CallRouter.route(CallRouter.java:247)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink.doWork(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:360)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.management.connector.ipc.IPCConnectorInboundLink$IPCConnectorReadCallback.complete(IPCConnectorInboundLink.java:602)
>
> at
>   com.ibm.ws.ssl.channel.impl.SSLReadServiceContext$SSLReadCompletedCallback.complete(SSLReadServiceContext.java:1784)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.tcp.channel.impl.AioReadCompletionListener.futureCompleted(AioReadCompletionListener.java:165)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AbstractAsyncFuture.invokeCallback(AbstractAsyncFuture.java:217)
>     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.AsyncChannelFuture.fireCompletionActions(AsyncChannelFuture.java:161)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.AsyncFuture.completed(AsyncFuture.java:138)     at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.complete(ResultHandler.java:204)   at
>   com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler.runEventProcessingLoop(ResultHandler.java:775)
>     at com.ibm.io.async.ResultHandler$2.run(ResultHandler.java:905)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1815) Caused by:
>   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   org.springframework.web.context.WebApplicationContext     at
>   java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:434)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.findClass(ExtClassLoader.java:204)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClassHelper(ClassLoader.java:688)  at
>   java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:667)     at
>   com.ibm.ws.bootstrap.ExtClassLoader.loadClass(ExtClassLoader.java:119)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:62)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.ProtectionClassLoader.loadClass(ProtectionClassLoader.java:58)
>     at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)    at
>   com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:584)
>     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:650)    ... 72 more

Answer (score 0):

As the stacktrace says:

> The annotations could not be obtained because of the exception : java.lang.**NoClassDefFoundError**: org.springframework.web.context.**WebApplicationContext**

Your spring-web-xyz.jar is not loaded. Make sure it is located in the classpath, i.e. using the admin app. It should be here somewhere: Servers -> ApplicationServers -> Servername -> Process Definition -> Java Virtual Machine.

Comment: As I've written, the spring-web is in the WAR archive within EAR. It was never in server's classpath. It is also not allowed to be there. Why would newer version require that?

Comment: The libraries from your EAR or WARs are added to your apps classpath at startup. I think you have a configuration problem with your classloaders.